# How to Left Join Databricks when duplicate keys error

Tags: sql, hive, left-join, databricks

I'm trying to do a LEFT join but I'm getting this error since the join key fields are duplicated in the resulting data table:

"Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the table definition of `schema`.`a_joined`: `order_nbr`, `user_id`;"

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schema.a_joined;
CREATE TABLE schema.a_joined STORED AS parquet
LOCATION 's3://user-data/gck/user/schema.a_joined' AS

SELECT 
  schema.a.*,
  schema.b.*
FROM 
  schema.a
LEFT JOIN 
  schema.b ON
  schema.b.ORDER_NBR = schema.a.order_nbr AND 
  schema.b.ORDER_DT = schema.a.trans_dt
WHERE 
  trans_dt BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Comment: Always write fields list out, do not use `select *`

Comment: There are over 50 fields in the table I'm trying to join, that would take ages

Comment: One-time task, takes much less time than attempting to outsmart sql engine. Use excel, notepad++ and other handy text processors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL standard supports a form of `JOIN` that uses `USING` instead of `ON`.  This allows `SELECT *` without fetching duplicate columns.  Alas, Hive does not support that.

Probably the simplest you can do is to select all columns from one table and then list the columns from the second table:

```
SELECT a.*, b.col1, b.col2, . . . 
FROM 
  schema.a a LEFT JOIN 
  schema.b b
  ON b.ORDER_NBR = a.order_nbr AND 
     b.ORDER_DT =  a.trans_dt
WHERE a.trans_dt BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31';
```

Note the use of table aliases and qualified column references.  These simplify the query so it is easier to write and read.  I assume that `trans_dt` is from `a` -- otherwise the `LEFT JOIN` is turned into an `INNER JOIN`.

As a note:  I would recommend writing the `WHERE` condition as:

```
WHERE a.trans_dt >= '2020-01-01' AND
      a.trans_dt < '2021-01-01;
```

Why?  This works for both dates and date/times.  This returns all rows where `trans_dt` is in 2020, regardless of whether or not `trans_dt` has a time component.